# Is there a way to restrict communication between two containers on the same pod to have improved isolation?

Tags: containers, kubernetes

I have deployed two containers on a pod. One is privileged and the other is a normal user container. I want to restrict communication between the two containers so that they cannot access each other or talk to each other on local host.

Comment: Why do you have them in the same pod to begin with if you need them isolated?

Comment: It will be a two container pod where one container is a privileged container responsible for debugging and introspecting other containers in that pod. Now I want this privileged container to not be accessible by the normal user container.

Answer (score 0):

As long as this privileged container has no applications listening, there shouldn't be any reason for these two containers to talk to each other. In case it has any kind of application listening, make sure to add any kind of authentication so it prevents any unwanted communication.

Comment: Containers in the same Pod can communicate with each other using `localhost` and need not have a service.

Comment: I did not mean service in the sense of k8s service. I meant an application that creates an IP socket in any of the containers.

Answer (score 0):

Containers on the same Pod share the same network namespace and can reach each other on `localhost`. It as if the pods are on the same computer/machine/vm.

See here:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/#resource-sharing-and-communication

and here:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/

Comment: I understand that. But is there a way to restrict this communication?